# ¿Cómo crear un arreglo asociativo en C#?

Tags: c#, array, diccionarios

Estoy leyendo un archivo excel que contiene fecha y hora, por ejemplo:

```
Id | fecha
1    2018-06-01 08:00
1    2018-06-01 12:00
1    2018-06-02 08:10
1    2018-06-02 12:40
```

Lo que quiero es obtener un arreglo del tipo:

```
[
  "2018-06-01" => [08:00, 12:00],
  "2018-06-02" => [08:10, 12:40]
]
```

Lo que tengo hasta el momento es:

```
Dictionary<string, ArrayList> test = new Dictionary<string, ArrayList>();
ArrayList listahora = new ArrayList();

for (int iRow = 2; iRow <= xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count; iRow++){  // inicia desde la segunda fila.
  DateTime f = xlWorkSheet.Cells[iRow, 4].value; //Aquí obtengo el valor del archivo excel
  string fecha = f.ToString().Split(' ')[0];
  string hora = f.ToString().Split(' ')[1];

  if (!test.ContainsKey(fecha))
  {
    listahora.Add(hora);
    test.Add(fecha, listahora);
  }
  else
  {
    listahora.Add(hora);
    test[fecha] = listahora;
  }
}
```

Sin embargo esto me crea un arreglo del tipo:

```
[
  "2018-06-01" => [08:00, 12:00, 08:10, 12:40],
  "2018-06-02" => [08:00, 12:00, 08:10, 12:40]
]
```

**¿Cómo podría obtener el arreglo que necesito?**

Comment: Supongo que tienes un bucle que no enseñas en este codigo.  Deberias de mostrarlo para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Si eso esta dentro de un bucle, ahora edito la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es vaciar la lista en cada iteracion.  Eso lo puedes lograr simplemente moviendo la declaracion dentro del bucle.  Algo asi:

```
Dictionary<string, ArrayList> test = new Dictionary<string, ArrayList>();    

for (int iRow = 2; iRow <= xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count; iRow++){  // inicia desde la segunda fila.
  ArrayList listahora = new ArrayList();
  DateTime f = xlWorkSheet.Cells[iRow, 4].value; //Aquí obtengo el valor del archivo excel
  string fecha = f.ToString().Split(' ')[0];
  string hora = f.ToString().Split(' ')[1];

  if (!test.ContainsKey(fecha))
  {
    listahora.Add(hora);
    test.Add(fecha, listahora);
  }
  else
  {       
    test[fecha].Add(hora);
  }
}
```

Comment: Si lo intente, pero al ser un solo bucle, eso me deja el ultimo valor, quedando un arreglo de la forma ´[
  "2018-06-01" => [12:00],
  "2018-06-02" => [12:40]
]´

Comment: Nota la parte del `else`, es diferente a la tuya

Comment: Ok, gracias ahora si funciono, no me había dado cuenta.